# Mac Pro 2019 Catalina

Tags: mac, catalina

I have a Mac Pro 2019 running Catalina.  I can connect to it using my MacBook Pro, my other Mac Pro, my iMac and share screens without a problem, but his Mac Pro will not connect to any of my other computers on my LAN.  I have tried all the common tricks, I can ping the other computers from the Mac Pro, but it refuses to connect, even though it sees the other computers on the network in the finder.  It says "connecting" but it never does.

Comment: Are these Windows computers? What protocol are they serving?

Comment: what if you click on "connect as..." and enter your username and password? It may be that the keychain password it *thinks* it should use is incorrect, damaged or just not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

On the Macs you wish to connect to from your Catalina host: Open `System Preferences`, click the `Sharing` icon, and select the preferences for sharing.

If you're trying to connect to Windows PCs, you'll need to do something else :)